# Criar pastas no KCFinder

Tags: php, javascript, html, kcfinder

Há alguma maneira/configuração para criar pastas pelo **KCFinder** no diretório de uploads dele?

Ex: O diretório padrão é /images, dentro dele gostaria de criar outras pastas pelo próprio KCFinder, porém não achei esta opção.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Sei que poderia usar o php para criar as pastas, mas seria melhor (principalmente para o cliente) se pudesse fazer isso pelo próprio **KCFinder**.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro do arquivo config.php na raiz do CKFinder você indica um local com a cadeia de pastas a serem carregadas no bloco "Backends":

```
    $config['backends'][] = array(
    'name'         => 'default',
    'adapter'      => 'local',
    'baseUrl'      => '../../../../home/SEU DIRETÓRIO/',
    'root'         => '', // Can be used to explicitly set the CKFinder user files directory.
    'chmodFiles'   => 0777,
    'chmodFolders' => 0755,
    'filesystemEncoding' => 'UTF-8',
);
```

E no bloco logo abaixo, você indica as pastas raiz desse apontamento no bloco "Resource Types":

```
$config['resourceTypes'][] = array(
    'name'              => 'Caixa',
    'directory'         => 'CAIXA',
    'maxSize'           => 0,
    'allowedExtensions' => '7z,aiff,asf,avi,bmp,csv,doc,docx,fla,flv,gif,gz,gzip,jpeg,jpg,mid,mov,mp3,mp4,mpc,mpeg,mpg,ods,odt,pdf,png,ppt,pptx,pxd,qt,ram,rar,rm,rmi,rmvb,rtf,sdc,sitd,swf,sxc,sxw,tar,tgz,tif,tiff,txt,vsd,wav,wma,wmv,xls,xlsx,zip',
    'deniedExtensions'  => '',
    'backend'           => 'default'
);
```